# grails war deployed on tomcat is not connecting to database

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I have deployed my war file that contains grails application on tomcat of a machine. On running the server, the application starts up but it is not connecting to the database mySql db. all the connection details are correct.

Do i need to do some additional setting for database connection ?

Comment: for sure there is an error message you can share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify the DB settings in 'production'. Running grails locally via run-app by default uses the 'development' database settings, while a deployed war will use the 'production' DB settings.